# Can channels send a message to different queues?

Tags: ibm-mq

I was reading some information about the difference between the message channels and the message queues,

> I understand that the channel is used for connecting to a queue
>   manager and not to a queue.

So the channel can retrieve/send message to different queues or just a particular queue? But when a producer needs to place a message into a queue, it specifies the name of the queue and the queue manager, but if that information was specified by the producer is not needed that the channel knows that information, right?

When is has a Publish/Subscribe messaging style, is always used a sender/receiver channel?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me.  There are various types of channels, in the simplest break down there are channels that allow queue managers to connect to each other and there are channels that allow client application to connect over the network to a queue manager.

Comment: Both types of channels can be configured to restrict the queues they would allow access to, so in that sense a specific channel will have access only to what you allow, if the channel runs as the MQ admin account (For example `mqm`) then it has access to all queues on the queue manager.  SVRCONN (also MQTT and AMQP) are used by a client application to both send and receive data from a queue manager.  Queue manger to queue manager channels are one direction, if you need to send both directions you would have two separate pairs.

Comment: A client application needs to specify information about how to connect to the queue manager, like hostname, port number, channel name and it would need to know names of queues or topic to open.  Publish/Subscribe is not tied to a sender/receiver channels, these are just used to send messages from one queue manager to another.  While in certain cases you could publish something on one queue manager that would then go to a "subscriber" over a sender/receive channel, that is just one use case for a sender/receive and not a very common one.

Comment: Yes, but I am confused If the channels can only retrieve/sent message a particular queue or can retrieve/sent messages a multiple queues?. When we are sending a message we are saying "send a message to queue A through channel B" then? We can use the channel B to send a meesage to queue C, for example

Comment: That is correct.   Other that permissions there is no correlation between channels and queues.   You can put to or get from any queue a connection to a SVRCONN has permission for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **message channel** connects together two queue managers. There are various different pairs of channel types that have slightly different behaviours, but all those types which send from one queue manager to the other are the same from the perspective of your question. For the rest of this answer I will use the SENDER-RECEIVER pair.

A SENDER channel will **ALWAYS** read from one queue - a transmission queue. It is named on the SENDER channel definition. The transmission queue is a safe storage area for the message until it is successfully transmitted to the the target queue manager.

An application connected to the sending queue manager can put messages to many different queues on the target queue manager and they will all, initially, be stored on the transmission queue.

This is possible because the queue manager adds a special header (called a transmission header - MQXQH) to the front of the message while it resides on the transmission queue. This header contains the target queue name and the target queue manager name as provided originally by the message producer. The channel does not know this information, it is provided by the producer.

Once the channel has moved the message across the network to the target queue manager, the RECEIVER channel removes the transmission header and uses the data in it, the queue name and queue manager name, to put the message to the appropriate queue.

In this way a single channel pair can deliver messages to many different queues.

Comment: I got it, Thanks you so much